# Publish test jar with dependencies in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I wrote the tests for my project under src/integTests directory and now I have to build and publish only jar generated out of integ tests. Here is my code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integTestJar (type:Jar) {
    from sourceSets.integTest.output
        appendix = 'integ-tests'
}

publishing {
      publications {
          myPublicationName(MavenPublication) {
              artifactId "client-security-internal-integ-tests"
              from components.java            
          }
      }
      repositories {
          maven {
              url ="${artifactory_contextUrl}"
              credentials {
                  username = "${artifactory_user}"
                  password = "${artifactory_password}"
              }
          }
      }
}
```

In the above, when I have `from components.java`, it publishes the product's jar with name as specified in artifact-id. Instead when I use `artifact integTestJar.archivePath`, it publishes the right jar but does not include the dependencies info in the pom file.

I tried `from components.integTest`, but that fails with error `Could not find property 'integTest' on SoftwareComponentInternal set`

How do I publish the integ-test jar with all its dependencies included in pom file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution which works!

```
        pom.withXml {
            def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
            configurations.integTestRuntime.getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
            }
        }
```